Plot fourier transform function of anonymous function
I am trying to plot the fourier function of a combination of ramp functions
I defined my original function as following: x = @(t) r(t + 1) - 2 * r(t) + r(t - 1); such that I will use it again.
I had some issues while trying to find and plot the FT of x such that the amplitude of X(w) is not as supposed to be. in the code in "X1 = fft(x1)/(length(t)/100);" I had to multiply fft by100 to have the correct amplitude but I cannot get why
my new code:
FS=50000;
t = linspace(-50,50,FS); % time-axis
w=linspace(-FS/2,FS/2,length(t));  % frequency axis

% Define the functions and parameters
r = @(t) t .* (t >= 0);
S = 7;
G = 8;

% Original signal x(t)
figure(1);
x = @(t) r(t + 1) - 2 * r(t) + r(t - 1);
x1 = x(t);
plot(t, x1, 'r-', 'LineWidth', 2);
xlabel('time in sec (t)');
ylabel('x(t)');
title('Plot of x(t)');
grid on;
xlim([-5, 5]);

% Fourier Transform
% FT of x(t)
figure(6);
X1 = fft(x1)/(length(t)/100);
R1=fftshift(X1);
plot(w, abs(R1), 'r-', 'LineWidth', 1);
xlabel('angular frequency (rad/sec)');
ylabel('amplitude');
title('Plot of X(w)');
grid on;
xlim([-50000, 50000]);



This question appears to only be about Matlab. Is there a reason you tagged it with [tag:matplotlib], a Python plotting library?

@CrisLuengo I got what you mean but actually there is no plotting at all, I updated the question with a photo of the plot

@CrisLuengo yes I understood that issue and its plotting now! Thanks A LOT.  but however there is an issue in the amplitude. I updated the question with the new code

Please edit your post so that it's one single, clear question. Don't leave your whole path in there, it's just going to confuse people. As long as you don't have any actual answers (these here are just comments), it is perfectly fine to change your question.

Also, please tell us why you think that dividing by 100 gives the right amplitude. What are you using to determine what is the right amplitude? Note that the FFT computes the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform), not the continuous-domain Fourier Transform. You are doing something different!

In particular, if you do X1 = fft(x1), then sum(x1) is the same as X1(1) (the 0 frequency component). If you expect the zero frequency component to be equal to the integral over your signal (as in the FT), then you should multiply X1 by the distance between samples.

@CrisLuengo I calculated the amplitude by doing ft calculations, and from there I could get the amplitude information and the frequencies where it intersects with x axis. And the professor approved the hand calculations so I am quite sure about them. And dividing the length by 100 then divided it with FFT will give amplitude equals one as it supposed to be

Right. And as I said, the DFT computes sum(x1) for the 0 frequency component, the FT computes the integral, which includes a dt. Your dt in the discrete world is the sample spacing, t(2)-t(1). Multiply by that instead of dividing by the length divided by 100.

In the following MATLAB script :
the signal is built directly with triang

signal power values on time and spectral domain match

the frequency reference for |X(f)| is aligned

datatips (markers) are placed on both main lobe and 1st side lobe getting ~27dB consistent with triangular and sawtooth pulses.


.
clear all;close all;clc
% Fs=50kHz and signal time span 100 seconds is way to apart
Fs=50000;    % [Hz] frequency
dts=1/Fs;    % [s] time

.
tp1=-.1;tp2=.1;                   % pulse window
t1=-.5;t2=.5;                      % pulse + gap window
     
t=[t1:dts:t2];                      % total pulse time window
tp=[tp1:dts:tp2];                 % busy pulse time window
Tp=tp(end)-tp(1);               % busy pulse delay
Ts=t(end)-t(1);                   % total pulse delay
     
np1=floor(abs(t1-tp1)/dts);  % busy pulse starts
dnp=floor(Tp/dts);              % busy pulse length
np2=np1+dnp;                    % busy pulse stops
     
% pulse definition
% r = @(t) t .* (t >= 0);
% fx = @(t) r(t + tp2) - dnp* dts * r(t) + r(t - tp1);
% xp=fx(tp);
xp=triang(dnp);
     
x=zeros(1,numel(t));
x([np1:np2-1])=xp(:);
     
% time domain
     
figure(1);
ax1=gca
plot(ax1,t,x);
title(ax1,'base pulse');xlabel(ax1,'t[s]');
     
exportgraphics(ax1,['upload_01.jpg'],'Resolution',100)
     
f=linspace(-Fs/2,Fs/2,length(t));  % [Hz] frequency points
     
% aligning frequency reference for X(f)
    flabels=round(linspace(f(1),f(end),11)/1e3,0);
    nflabels=25002+floor(flabels*1e3/50e3*numel(f));
    nflabels(2:end)=10*round((nflabels(2:end))/10);
flabels=f(nflabels)+25001;
flabels(1)=0;
     
cellf={};
for k1=1:1:numel(flabels)
  cellf{k1}=num2str(1e-2*round( f(nflabels(k1))/10));
end
     
Px=1/numel(x)*sum(x.^2)/Ts     % [W] x(t) signal power
X1 = 1/(numel(f))*fft(x,numel(f));
X1(1)=[];                                  % trick to make center max(abs(X)) right on 0Hz
X=fftshift(X1);
absX=abs(X);
sum(abs(X).^2)                     % overall |X(f)|^2 area is signal power
     
% spectrum domain
     
figure(2)
ax2=gca
hp1=plot(10*log10(abs(X).^2))
     
title('                              10 LOG10 |X(f)|^2');xlabel('f [kHz]');
grid on
grid minor
ax2.XTick=flabels
ax2.XTickLabels=cellf
     
axis(ax2,[24925 25075 -100 -10])
     
    datip1=datatip(ax2.Children,25000,-20.28);
    datip2=datatip(ax2.Children,25015,-46.60);
     
exportgraphics(ax2,['upload_02.jpg'],'Resolution',100)
 
 



